# Is US20110252845 really novel?

Tags: prior-art, us20110252845

[US20110252845](http://www.google.com/patents/US20110252845) does not seem novel to me.

Possible prior art:
http://www.adaez.com/files/yalepress.pdf (Designing a Door Energy Harvesting Device, 2010, Joey Brink, Ryan Carlisle, Kenny Leveille, ... Yale, MENG 489).